# Is it possible to assign a php variable to a jquery var and then refresh that jquery variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Is it possible to assign a php variable to a jQuery variable and then use a function to refresh the jQuery var every 30 seconds?

Also, could you use that variable in a html input?

```
<input type="text" value="jquery value that will refresh every 30 seconds with PHP variable">
```

If this is possible how and where can you learn to do this?

Comment: It is, but to refresh the serverside code without reloading the page you'll need ajax.

Comment: additionally you have to return a JSON or XML to get it compatible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this. Just change backend url. This backend should only output the value.

```
<input id="input" type="text" value="" />

<script>
setInterval(function(){
    $.get( "/value.php", function( data ) {
      $('#input').val( data );
    });
},30000);
</script>
```

Your `value.php` file will look something like

```
<?php 
$value = 1;

echo $value;
exit;
```

---

If you need to return more values then one, you can use JSON, then

```
<input id="input" type="text" value="" />

<script>
setInterval(function(){
    $.get( "/value.php", function( data ) {
      $('#input').val( data.first_value );
    }, "json");
},30000);
</script>
```

Your `value.php` file will look something like

```
<?php 
$first_value = 1;
$second_value = "Some string";

echo json_encode(array(
    'first_value' => $first_value,
    'second_value' => $second_value
));
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

This script only sends data to fiddle servers which in turn send it back. It then update the value of the input.

It's just a little [example](http://jsfiddle.net/mqgdjebr/2/) but it might help you to get the idea:

```
var data_sent = 1;
setInterval(function () {// Set interval to retrieve info every 1s.
    $.ajax({
        url: "/echo/json/",// URL provided by jsfiddle to try AJAX. It just echoes back.
        type: 'POST',// jsfiddle imposes that you use POST for that url.
        data: {
            json: JSON.stringify(data_sent)// Send data, it'll be echoed by jsfiddle script, the format is also imposed by jsfiddle.
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#myInput").val(data);// Put the data received in the input
            data_sent += 1;// change the data so that you send new one to the server next time.
        }
    })
}, 1000);
```